# ¿Cómo puedo mantener mi toggle en la misma posición que lo coloque aunque pase a otro apartado?

Tags: javascript, diseño, programación-bajo-nivel

tengo mi pagina que tiene dos modos, uno claro y otro oscuro que se activan por medio de la posición de toggle, intentándolo logre que se guardara solo un thema y así se queda, en pocas palabras, antes de modificarlo el modo inicial era el modo claro, ahora el modo principal es el oscuro, alguien sabe porque?
[image: MI JAVASCRIPT]
[image: MI PAGINA]

Comment: No se si esa es la causa, pero en el último `if` que muestras pase lo que pase, siempre va a agregar el **modo oscuro**. Tanto en el `if` como en el `else`. Ese `if` no tiene sentido así como está.

Comment: Lo otro es, que con cambiar el contenido de la variable en el `localStorage`, no estás cambiando el estilo de tu página. Cuando se hace click en el `modeSwitch` sí, se cambia el contenido de la variable en el storage, pero nunca estás cambiando la clase en el body. Asegúrate de agregar o quitar la clase en body dentro del `callback` en el eventListener. El código que cambia la clase está actualmente fuera del `callback` y solo será ejecutado una vez cuando se cargue tu página web.

Comment: Por favor, no pegues imágenes para mostrar código, hazlo en modo texto para facilitarnos ayudarme y darte buenas respuestas sin tener que escribirlo nosotros a pelo para mostrártelas.  Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender mejor el funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias